# measure length of silence at beginning of audio file (wav)

Tags: python, audio, unity-game-engine

I went through all post about measuring silence, unfortunately I have not been able to find a solution for my problem.

I have about 3000 audio files. Each file is 10 second long and is a recording of someone saying a word at loud.

I need to know how long it took for them to say the word (= silence before the word is said).
I read I can do it with the formula  audioop.rms(fragment, width), but I can not find instruction on how to use it.

New Error:

```
void@control:~/Documents$ python audio.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "audio.py", line 36, in <module>
    leading_silences = {a: get_silence(a, threshold) for a in audio_files}
  File "audio.py", line 36, in <dictcomp>
    leading_silences = {a: get_silence(a, threshold) for a in audio_files}
  File "audio.py", line 7, in get_silence
    song = AudioSegment.from_wav(audio)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 471, in from_wav
    return cls.from_file(file, 'wav')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 387, in from_file
    file = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(file, 'rb', tempfile=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydub/utils.py", line 59, in _fd_or_path_or_tempfile
    fd = open(fd, mode=mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'silbato.wav'
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would make an attempt at solving the problem, and post that in minimal form, and explain what doesn't work with your attempt.  Most people don't just want to do your work for you.

Comment: Hi, I did not want anyone to do the work for me, but I was asking for a place where to start from.

Comment: Once I have something to start with, I will do as you say . Thanks for the advice

Comment: See the latest edit below for the solution (joining the path to the path to the audio file with the name on AudioSegment instantiation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the lovely [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) library by @jiarro:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def get_silence(audio, threshold, interval):
    "get length of silence in seconds from a wav file"

    # swap out pydub import for other types of audio
    song = AudioSegment.from_wav(audio)

    # break into chunks
    chunks = [song[i:i+interval] for i in range(0, len(song), interval)]

    # find number of chunks with dBFS below threshold
    silent_blocks = 0
    for c in chunks:
        if c.dBFS == float('-inf') or c.dBFS < threshold:
            silent_blocks += 1
        else:
            break

    # convert blocks into seconds
    return round(silent_blocks * (interval/1000), 3)

# get files in a directory
audio_path = 'path/to/directory'
audio_files = [i for i in listdir(audio_path) if isfile(join(audio_path, i))]

threshold = -80 # tweak based on signal-to-noise ratio

interval = 1 # ms, increase to speed up

leading_silences = {a: get_silence(join(audio_path, a),
                                   threshold, interval) for a in audio_files}

# to get tab-separated values:
for name, leading_silence in leading_silences.items():
    print(''.join([name, '\t', str(leading_silence)]))
```

Comment: Thank Alec.  Thanks very much for your advice.

Comment: I am running it but it does not generate any output.... is the last line the one meant to create a file with the output?

Comment: @alexkirke yeah, you can either print(leading_silences) or use the dict to cut up the audio right in the script! (I can help if you need)

Comment: @alexkirke I edited the answer to output all the names and leading silences. Remember that you might need to increase or decrease the threshold!

Comment: That's beautiful! Thanks. Now I have the output. I work with really small silence, so I guess I can change 50 and use 1, to get more chunks.

Comment: @alexkirke glad to hear it!

Comment: one question more, how can I define audio_files as a whole directory rather than individual files? That way I can run it thought a whole folder and output all in a .txt : I am trying by defining the route but I think that is not the logic..

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for your help and clear comments. I really appreciate it.

Comment: done. Not sure there is a -1 thought.. may I ask you something? Last night script was working nicely. Today, it does work for single files but not for folders. I've tried to remove and install again the library.

Comment: @alexkirke the issue was that the file path wasn't added to the AudioSegment import so it couldn't find them. The latest edit should do the trick.

Comment: .dBFS? What is that?

Comment: @datWooWoo it stands for "decibels relative to full scale". The decibel is just a measure of the ratio between two values on a logarithmic scale - it cannot be used to measure loudness without also referring to some reference level. The "full scale" qualifier is often used as that reference point when working with digital audio, and defines the reference point of 0 dBFS as the point where the encoded signal is at the maximum possible amplitude (meaning that there is no headroom left and any additional increase will clip the signal). This implies that any dBFS value must be zero or negative.