# Detecting speech vs. non-speech at edges with Python + pydub

Tags: python, audio, pydub

I have a large number of audio files that are somewhat noisy and not completely parallel to each other (different voices, different levels of background noise).

I want to count the length of time at the beginning and end of each recording that is not human speech. That is, each recording has the shape of: <0: noise, 1: speech, 2: noise> and I want the duration of 0 and 2.

I have written a script that is doing more or less what I want by searching from the start and end of a file at a variable dbFS threshold, but in some cases it fails to find a reasonable value. Possibly, it's impossible bc the files are too noisy, but maybe there's a better method than what I have implemented (e.g. something other than volume to look at, or some smarter algorithm).

https://gist.github.com/moui72/6f537928b04443fba9ca575573488263

If anyone has advice as to how to improve my precision and/or get results from a larger percentage of the noisy files, I'd be grateful.

Note: I wrote my script based on Alec's response to [measure length of silence at beginning of audio file (wav)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231328/measure-length-of-silence-at-beginning-of-audio-file-wav)